# Sonarqube migration 6.7.7 LTS to 7.9 => ERROR: relation “live_measures” already exists (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sonarqube

Database (PostgreSQL) migration failed with ‘Create table live_measures’ failed, caused by

```
ERROR: relation "live_measures" already exists
```

when updating SonarQube from 6.7.7 LTS to 7.9 LTS

```
2019.07.12 07:25:41 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] Starting DB Migration and container restart
2019.07.12 07:25:41 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] Executing DB migrations...
2019.07.12 07:25:41 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1930 'Add QUALITY_GATES.IS_BUILT_IN'...
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1930 'Add QUALITY_GATES.IS_BUILT_IN': success | time=177ms
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1931 'Populate QUALITY_GATES.IS_BUILT_IN'...
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.s.MassUpdate] 3 quality_gates processed (0 items/sec)
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1931 'Populate QUALITY_GATES.IS_BUILT_IN': success | time=64ms
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1932 'Make QUALITY_GATES.IS_BUILT_IN not null'...
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1932 'Make QUALITY_GATES.IS_BUILT_IN not null': success | time=62ms
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1933 'Remove quality gates loaded templates'...
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.s.MassUpdate] 1 delete loaded templates for quality gate processed (0 items/sec)
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1933 'Remove quality gates loaded templates': success | time=16ms
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1934 'Rename quality gate "SonarQube way" to "Sonar way"'...
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.s.MassUpdate] 1 quality gates processed (0 items/sec)
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1934 'Rename quality gate "SonarQube way" to "Sonar way"': success | time=9ms
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1935 'Drop LOADED_TEMPLATES table'...
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1935 'Drop LOADED_TEMPLATES table': success | time=133ms
2019.07.12 07:25:42 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1936 'Delete person measures'...
2019.07.12 07:26:26 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.s.MassUpdate] 66219 snapshots processed (1103 items/sec)
2019.07.12 07:26:26 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1936 'Delete person measures': success | time=44397ms
2019.07.12 07:26:26 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1937 'Drop index on project_measures.person_id'...
2019.07.12 07:26:26 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1937 'Drop index on project_measures.person_id': success | time=22ms
2019.07.12 07:26:26 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1938 'Create table live_measures'...
2019.07.12 07:26:26 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] #1938 'Create table live_measures': failure | time=27ms
2019.07.12 07:26:26 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] Executed DB migrations: failure | time=44914ms
2019.07.12 07:26:26 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] DB migration failed | time=45028ms
2019.07.12 07:26:26 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] DB migration ended with an exception
org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepExecutionException: Execution of migration step #1938 'Create table live_measures' failed
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:79)
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:52)
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.engine.MigrationEngineImpl.execute(MigrationEngineImpl.java:68)
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.DatabaseMigrationImpl.doUpgradeDb(DatabaseMigrationImpl.java:105)
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.DatabaseMigrationImpl.doDatabaseMigration(DatabaseMigrationImpl.java:80)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute CREATE TABLE live_measures (uuid VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,project_uuid VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,component_uuid VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,metric_id INTEGER NOT NULL,value NUMERIC (38,20) NULL,text_value VARCHAR (4000) NULL,variation NUMERIC (38,20) NULL,measure_data BYTEA NULL,update_marker VARCHAR (40) NULL,created_at BIGINT NOT NULL,updated_at BIGINT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_live_measures PRIMARY KEY (uuid))
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:97)
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:77)
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:117)
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.version.v70.CreateTableLiveMeasures.execute(CreateTableLiveMeasures.java:53)
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange.execute(DdlChange.java:45)
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:75)
... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "live_measures" already exists
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:175)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:175)
at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:82)
```

Comment: The official answer is to restore your database and try it again. But first try to delete the table mentioned by hand and try to start the migration again. Check the end result if this succeeds and keep your saved database for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Thank’s so much @jeroen-heier
That pointed me to the right direction. After

```
DROP TABLE "live_measures";
ALTER TABLE organization_alm_bindings DROP COLUMN members_sync_enabled;
ALTER TABLE webhooks DROP COLUMN secret;
```

the migration finished successful. Thank you.